Domain name keeps routing to old site randomly
I recently routed my new domain name to my azure static web app and successfully linked the TXT and A record. I am using go daddy as my DNS provider. After successfully validating the domain name on azure static web app. It temporarily showed the new web app whenever I would click the web application. Now it goes in and out from the new page and the default go daddy template site.

Have you added 301 redirects from your old site to the new site?

Yes didnt seem to work

Without knowing the domain name in question Its impossible to definitively answer, but this sounds very much like the nameservers are still updating and/or one or more of the nameservers is incorrect.
It is also remotely possible (but admittedly unlikely from your description) that its a caching issue - what happens if you flush your browser cache?
